# pandas dataframe loc multiple condition another variation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have one dataframe df and a date

```
last_date_pm = datetime.date(2022,12,30)
```

RiskDate,valStart,valEnd columns are also date of same format as of last_date_pm

I want to call

```
df_s = df.loc[((df['RiskDate'] == df['valStart']) & (df['valEnd'] != last_date_pm)), ['Start'] + selected_cols]
```

result for this comes as empty as seemingly this 'and' logic is not working as expected.
I tried to print df['RiskDate'] == df['valStart']
it comes as

```
0 False
1 True
2 False
dtype: bool
```

but this df['valEnd'] != last_date_pm
comes as

```
0 True
1 True
2 True
Name: valEnd, dtype: bool
```

Could the extra Name in the second condition be an issue ?

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: RiskDate object
valStart object
valEnd object 
dtype: object

Comment: If your 'valEnd' column contains datetime.date instances and is not a DatetimeIndex then your test works as expected. So what's wrong? Do you have any error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems compare `dates` with `datetimes`, so get always `False`.

One idea should by compare by Timestamp or datetime:

```
last_date_pm = pd.Timestamp('2022-12-30')
```

Or compare by dates:

```
last_date_pm = datetime.date(2022,12,30)
(df['valEnd'].dt.date != last_date_pm)
```

EDIT: Convert columns to datetimes and compare by string `2022-12-31`:

```
cols = ['RiskDate','valStart','valEnd']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

last_date_pm = '2022-12-31'
df_s = df.loc[((df['RiskDate'] == df['valStart']) & 
               (df['valEnd'] != last_date_pm)), ['Start'] + selected_cols]
```

Comment: This doing df['valEnd'].dt.date doesn't work as It throws attribute error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: both are datetime.date(2022,12,30)

Comment: @007 - Ic check EDIT it working?

Comment: with pd.to_datetime the valEnd columns gets converted to datetime64[ns]; but still the same thing, the loc condition makes it empty.

Comment: @007 - Can you add data sample to question?

Comment: Okay, let me add